# AoC Day 22: Sporifica Virus Part 1, a Solution in Beginner's Haskell

Tags: beginner, haskell

Until recently, I was very much only devoted to imperative languages (mainly C++ and C, to be precise), when I decided to venture into unknown waters by picking up a new, completely different language, which happened to be Haskell, a decision which happened to be influenced by the fact that I owned a copy of "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!", a book which I very much enjoyed learning from.

Some days ago, I finished said book, and, wanting to apply my newly acquired knowledge, ventured our to find some programming exercises. I quickly remembered Advent of Code, which offers a whole pre-Christmas period's worth of easy to mildly difficult programming problems, a few of which I had already solved during the holidays.

I skimmed through the exercises, looking for one simple enough to be conquerable with my still very inadequate and shaky Haskell skills, and finally chose the task of Day 22.

## Problem Description

> Diagnostics indicate that the local grid computing cluster has been
>   contaminated with the Sporifica Virus. The grid computing cluster is a
>   seemingly-infinite two-dimensional grid of compute nodes. Each node is
>   either clean or infected by the virus.
>
> To prevent overloading the nodes (which would render them useless to
>   the virus) or detection by system administrators, exactly one virus
>   carrier moves through the network, infecting or cleaning nodes as it
>   moves. The virus carrier is always located on a single node in the
>   network (the current node) and keeps track of the direction it is
>   facing.
>
> To avoid detection, the virus carrier works in bursts; in each burst,
>   it wakes up, does some work, and goes back to sleep. The following
>   steps are all executed in order one time each burst:
>
> - If the current node is infected, it turns to its right. Otherwise, it
>     turns to its left. (Turning is done in-place; the current node does
>     not change.)
> - If the current node is clean, it becomes infected.
>     Otherwise, it becomes cleaned. (This is done after the node is
>     considered for the purposes of changing direction.)
> - The virus carrier
>     moves forward one node in the direction it is facing. Diagnostics have
>     also provided a map of the node infection status (your puzzle input).
>
> Clean nodes are shown as .; infected nodes are shown as #. This map
>   only shows the center of the grid; there are many more nodes beyond
>   those shown, but none of them are currently infected.
>
> The virus carrier begins in the middle of the map facing up.

(The full puzzle description, including examples, is available on the official [AoC website](http://adventofcode.com/2017/day/22).)

The mentioned puzzle input consists of a file containing a grid of `.` and `#`.

## My Solution

```
import Data.List.Index
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import System.Environment
import System.IO
import qualified System.IO.Strict as IOS

type Position = (Int, Int)
type Dimensions = (Int, Int)
type NodeMap = Set.Set Position

data Rotation = Clockwise | Counterclockwise deriving (Eq, Show)
data Direction = North | East | South | West deriving (Eq, Show)


nextDirection :: Rotation -> Direction -> Direction
nextDirection rot dir
    | rot == Clockwise && dir == West         = North
    | rot == Clockwise && dir == East         = South
    | rot == Clockwise && dir == North        = East
    | rot == Clockwise && dir == South        = West
    | rot == Counterclockwise && dir == West  = South
    | rot == Counterclockwise && dir == East  = North
    | rot == Counterclockwise && dir == North = West
    | rot == Counterclockwise && dir == South = East

parseInput :: String -> (Dimensions, NodeMap)
parseInput s = ((length . head . lines $ s, length . lines $ s),
    foldl (\set (index, char) ->
        if char == '#'
            then Set.insert index set 
            else set)
    Set.empty
    . ifoldl (\ls index line ->
        ls ++ zipWith (\ix (i, char) -> 
            ((i, ix), char))
        (repeat index) (indexed line))
    []
    . lines $ s)

simulateNBurstsImpl :: Int -> (Int, Position, Direction, NodeMap)
    -> (Int, Position, Direction, NodeMap)
simulateNBurstsImpl 0 x = x
simulateNBurstsImpl i (count, pos, dir, map) = simulateNBurstsImpl
    (i - 1) transitionFunction 
    where
        step (a, b) dir
            | dir == West  = (a - 1, b)
            | dir == East  = (a + 1, b)
            | dir == North = (a, b - 1)
            | dir == South = (a, b + 1)
        transitionFunction 
            | Set.member pos map == True = let
                    nextDir = nextDirection Clockwise dir
                in (count, step pos nextDir, nextDir, Set.delete pos map)
            | Set.member pos map == False = let
                    nextDir = nextDirection Counterclockwise dir
                in (count + 1, step pos nextDir, nextDir, Set.insert pos map)

simulateNBursts :: Int -> Dimensions -> NodeMap -> Int
simulateNBursts i (width, height) map =
    first (simulateNBurstsImpl i (0, startingPos, North, map))
    where
        startingPos = (width `quot` 2, height `quot` 2)
        first (a, _, _, _) = a


main = getArgs >>= \(filename : _) ->
    withFile filename ReadMode IOS.hGetContents >>= \content ->
        let parsed = parseInput content in
        print . simulateNBursts 10000 (fst parsed) . snd $ parsed
```

Notes:

- The program takes a single argument on the commandline; the path to the file containing the starting grid.
- I decided on using a set as the underlying data structure as it makes it easy to work with growing grids. My first attempt used a two-dimensional sequence, but extending the grid turned out to be too much of a hassle for my taste.
- The code assumes that all inputs are valid, including the fact that a commandline parameter was passed and points to a valid file.

## Review Requests

Please feel free to review anything and everything that comes to mind! That said, I do have a few concrete questions:

1. Having `simulateNBursts` as a beautified interface to `simulateNBurstsImpl` seems kind of ugly to me. Is there a way to clean this up and join the two functions? Or is this a common pattern?
2. How readable is this code? As its author, I find it hard to judge how (un-)pleasant this code is to the eye of a third person, especially since I have next to no experience in reading and writing Haskell code. What can I do to improve readability?
3. `nextDirection` seems very verbose to me. Is there a more concise way to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inline `simulateNBurstsImpl` if you get rid of the recursion:

```
simulateNBurstsImpl n = foldr (.) id $ replicate n transitionFunction
```

Combining `zipWith` with `repeat` is a fool's errand. (I don't know where you get `ifoldl` and `indexed`, so I'll assume they start at 0.)

```
parseInput :: String -> (Dimensions, NodeMap)
parseInput s = ((length . head $ lines s, length $ lines s), Set.fromList
  [ (x, y)
  | (y, line) <- zip [0..] $ lines s
  , (x, char) <- zip [0..] line
  , char == '#'
  ])
```

`Direction` and `Rotation` can be directly represented as offsets and functions on offsets.

```
import Data.NumInstances.Tuple

type Rotation = Direction -> Direction
type Direction = (Int, Int)

transitionFunction (count, pos, (dx,dy), map) = if Set.member pos map
  then let nextdir = (-dy,dx)
    in (count    , pos + nextDir, nextDir, Set.delete pos map)
  else let nextdir = (dy,-dx)
    in (count + 1, pos + nextDir, nextDir, Set.insert pos map)
```

Optionally: `lens` and `State` specialize in this fiddly sort of stuff.

```
data S = S
  { _count :: Int
  , _pos :: Position
  , _dir :: Int
  , _map :: NodeMap
  }

makeLenses ''S

simulateNBursts i (width, height) map =
  (`evalState` (0, (width `quot` 2, height `quot` 2), (0,-1), map)) $ do
    replicateM_ i $ do
      hashtagged <- map . contains pos <<%= negate
      nextDir <- dir <%= \(x,y) -> if hashtagged then (-y,x) else (y,-x)
      pos += nextDir
      unless hashtagged $ count += 1
    use count
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. `ifoldl` and `indexed` are from the `ilist` package (from [Data.List.Index](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ilist-0.3.1.0/docs/Data-List-Index.html) and start, as you guessed, from 0.